# Running databasemigration with Grails IntegrationTest run - is it possible

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

So this is the problem I'm trying to work around:

I'm working with an old grails project using PosgreSQL, including GORM.  The domain classes are as minimal as GORM wants them to be  - so ID management is abstracted away into the default stuff and isn't spec'd in the domain classes at all.

The issue with this is that `dbCreate` (`create-drop`, FWIW) doesn't generate the `hibernate_sequence` sequence that it uses by default.

This has been fixed/bodged/compensated for with a liquibase changelog that creates it in other scenarios, but I'm trying to get H2 set up for IT tests.  I can create a persisted H2 db and manually add `hibernate_sequence` to get everything to work, but I'm struggling to find a way to get that to work when the IT tests are run.

I had tried to add (in `application.yml`):

```
grails:
  plugin:
    databasemigration:
      updateOnStart: true
      updateOnStartFileNames: ['changelog.groovy']
      autoMigrateScripts: ['TestApp']
```

`changelog.groovy` exists in `grails-app/migrations`, and `grails-app/migrations` is configured as a `sourceSet` in build.gradle.  All other aspects are correct and in place (dependencies etc.)

To check whether liquibase is actually running, I have set the changelog to execute trash SQL - which should cause an error - but it's instead failing on `Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found`, so is skimming over the issue.

Is what I'm attempting possible, or is there another way to make `dbCreate` generate the sequences itself?  I can't risk changing how it has been run for fear of changing how prod works, and I've attempted all sorts of hibernate config in application.yml, but I've run into a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

So, sometimes the simplest solutions may be the best. Would adding `data.sql` file to `src/integration-test/resources` work for you? This file is automatically recognized by Spring and executed after or before hibernate ddl is called - depending on your Spring Boot version and additional configuration options. It can contain any SQL script to be executed, in your case sequence creation.

More details are available here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html